# Vuejs2 window get the height scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to add a class of `sticky` to `navbar` whenever a user scrolls down and remove the class whenever the user scrolls to the top.

So basically I'm trying to find the height scrolled. I have:

```
mounted(){
    this.setUpRoutes();
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},

destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},

methods:{
    handleScroll(event){
        console.log("handling event scroll here", event.height());
    }
}
```

But am getting an error: `event.height() is not a function`

How do I determine the height scrolled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the scrollTop, not the offsetHeight only.

for example:

[Get scroll position and direction with vanilla JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205622/get-scroll-position-and-direction-with-vanilla-js)

```
mounted(){
    this.setUpRoutes();
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},
destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},

methods:{
 handleScroll(event){
    // I think   document.body.scrollTop is not FF compatible, but for example.
    console.log("handling event scroll here", {top: document.body.scrollTop, height: window.innerHeight });
  }

}
```

Comment: can you add the green V ?